# Page Does Not Scroll Down after appending data through jQuery append, before, after, prepend

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, append, contact-form-7

I have a Contact Form 7 here on this WordPress page. 
http://globaldonorsforum.org/register/

On change in the drop-down for No of Registrants, I generate input fields based on the number of people entered.

But after that page does not scroll down.

I am using custom JS to handle this functionality in Contact Form 7.

```js
$('#cf7-container-builder-1522388635110 select').on('change', function() {
      $('.appendInputs').remove();
      var limit = $('#cf7-container-builder-5594975 input').val();
      var val = parseInt(limit , 10);
      if (limit  != '') {
          for (var i = 1; i < val+1 ; i++) {
             
              $('#cf7-container-builder-1522405628622').before('<div class="appendInputs cf7-builder-container-row1 cf7-builder-container-row-inner cf7-main-builder dropped ui-sortable-handle" id="cf7-container-builder-1522405628622'+i+'"><div class="cf7-ctrl"><div class="cf7-move"></div><div class="cf7-colunm"></div><div class="cf7-dub cf7-dub-row"></div><div class="cf7-remove"></div></div><div class="cf7-row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="cf7-builder-container-row-inner-drop ui-droppable ui-sortable"><div class="cf7-text cf7-main-builder dropped cf7_input_icon ui-sortable-handle" id="cf7-container-builder-1522407137043"><div class="cf7-ctrl cf7-ctrl-inner"><div class="cf7-move"></div><div class="cf7-edit"></div><div class="cf7-dub cf7-dub-text"></div><div class="cf7-remove"></div></div><div class="cf7_text_label">Additional Registrant '+i+'</div><div class="cf7_font"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="cf7_text_shortcode"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap addRegistrant'+i+'"><input type="text" name="addRegistrant'+i+'" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
          }
      }
      
     if ($('#cf7-container-builder-1522388635110 select').val()  ==  750){
        $('.appendInputs').remove();
      }
   
  });
```

I believe it's because after appending data it messes the scroll and HTML/body height. But I am unable to figure out. Any help?

Comment: This happens because the user stays focused on the dropdown. Thus, you should use .blur() to remove "focus".
Use `$("body").blur();` before ` $('.appendInputs').remove();` and it should be fine.

Comment: I tried it bro. No change in the behaviour.

Comment: I am using Avada. For now, I disabled the smooth scrolling and the issue is gone. I will submit a ticket to have them see what is the issue.